# Smoke resolution

Tags: shaders, smoke-simulation, resolution

For the last few days, I'm struggling with making a nice "fluffy" smoke. I watched so many tutorials... I tried each of them and somehow I didn't get what I wanted, till today.

I managed to achieve the "look", but my clouds have square edges and are kind of blurry. I definitely messed up my render setting, and my smoke domain settings.

[image: sharp-edges-smoke]

I can only guess, that something with my shader is wrong or/and with my render properties. I'm really open to any advice!

P.S. I'm a newbie in Blender. Maybe this what I'm trying to do is not for me, but I started to do the tutorial for the Moon knight and got enthusiastic to do the smoke with Blender.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If you could [edit] your post to add any more information you can, as well as what the end result should be (i.e. is this supposed to be animated?) it would be a big help, as well as bump it up in the active questions queue for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what happens when you crank the density up too high on the shader. You can clearly see the smoke domain resolution.

To some extent, this is just the going rate with smoke simulations, though.

This is 128 divisions with default 5 density, and while the domain resolution is still visible in some areas, it's not as noticeable.

[image]

Also, in animation these artifacts would be smoothed over a bit.

But I suppose the solution is to suffer this in the viewport and then do a high resolution final bake.

Comment: Hello Allen, first thank you for the hint, and yes I pumped the density maybe too much as I hoped that this could fix my blurry smoke issue. Now when you mentioned I changed my density to 5 and with math node multiply with 30 value. Anyway if I reduce it more, does not affect it that much. My smoke is still not smooth and has this strange lines / edges. What I've found is, that for volumetric rendering I should increase the render properties of the Light paths, max bounces, volume from 0 to 2-5. But this also didn't fix my strange smoke edges.

Comment: @EJIEHA Understood, unfortunate :(